# Using tf.cond() to feed my graph for training and validation

Tags: tensorflow

In my TensorFlow code I want my network to take inputs from one of the two `StagingArea` objects depending upon whether I want to do training or testing. 
A part of the graph construction code I wrote is as follows :

```
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
      for i in range(numgpus):
          with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=i>0) as vscope:
              with tf.device('/gpu:{}'.format(i)):
                  with tf.name_scope('GPU-Tower-{}'.format(i)) as scope:
                      phase = tf.get_variable("phase", [], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),dtype=tf.uint8, trainable=False)
                      phaseassigntest = phase.assign(1)
                      phaseassigntrain = phase.assign(0)
                      phasetest = tf.equal(phase, 0)
                      is_training = tf.cond(phasetest, lambda: tf.constant(True), lambda: tf.constant(False))

                      trainstagingarea = tf.contrib.staging.StagingArea([tf.float32, tf.int32], shapes=[[trainbatchsize, 3, 221, 221], [trainbatchsize]], capacity=20)
                      putoptrain = trainstagingarea.put(train_iterator.get_next())
                      trainputop.append(putoptrain)
                      getoptrain = trainstagingarea.get()
                      traingetop.append(getoptrain)
                      trainclearop = trainstagingarea.clear()
                      trainstageclear.append(trainclearop)
                      trainsizeop = trainstagingarea.size()
                      trainstagesize.append(trainsizeop)

                      valstagingarea = tf.contrib.staging.StagingArea([tf.float32, tf.int32], shapes=[[valbatchsize, 3, 221, 221], [valbatchsize]], capacity=20)
                      putopval = valstagingarea.put(val_iterator.get_next())
                      valputop.append(putopval)
                      getopval = valstagingarea.get()
                      valgetop.append(getopval)
                      valclearop = valstagingarea.clear()
                      valstageclear.append(valclearop)
                      valsizeop = valstagingarea.size()
                      valstagesize.append(valsizeop)


                      #elem = valgetop[i]
                      elem = tf.cond(is_training,lambda: traingetop[i],lambda: valgetop[i])

                      img = elem[0]
                      label = elem[1]
                      labelonehot = tf.one_hot(label, depth=numclasses)
                      net, networksummaries =  overfeataccurate(img,numclasses=numclasses, phase=is_training)
```

I have used `tf.cond` to make sure that the network is fed by one of the two `StagingArea` objects. One is meant for training and the other one is meant for validation.
Now, when I try to execute the graph as follows, I do not get any result and infact the code just hangs and I have to kill the process.

```
with tf.Session(graph=g,config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(val_initialize)
    for i in range(20):
        sess.run(valputop)
        print(sess.run(valstagesize))
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('.', graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    epoch = 0
    iter = 0
    print("Performing Validation")
    sess.run(phaseassigntest)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    while(epoch<10):
        time_init = time.time()
        while True:
            try:
                [val_accu, _, summaries] = sess.run([towervalidation, towervalidationupdateop,validation_summary_op])
                print(val_accu)
```

when instead of `tf.cond()` I directly assign `elem = valgetop[i]`, the code works just fine.
Am I missing something over here ?

What is the right way to feed my network based on whether I want to do training or testing ?

**NOTE** The error does not go away even if  I set `numgpus` to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Your problem

#### What you think `tf.cond` does

Based on the flag, execute what is required to put either traingetop[i] or valgetop[i] into your `elem` tensor.

#### What `tf.cond` actually does

Executes what is required to get **both** traingetop[i] and valgetop[i], then passes one of them into your `elem` tensor.

#### So

The reason it is hanging forever is because it's waiting for an element to be added to your training staging area (so that it can get that element and discard it). You're forgiven for not realising this is what it's doing; it's actually very counter-intuitive. The documentation is **awfully** unclear on how to deal with this.

---

## Recommended Solution (by Tensorflow documentation)

If you really need the queues to be in the same graph, then you need to make two copies of your ENTIRE graph, one that is fed by your training staging area, and one that is fed by your validation staging area. Then you just use the relevant tensor in your `sess.run` call. I recommend creating a function that takes a queue output tensor, and returns a `model_output` tensor. Now you have a `train_time_output` tensor and a `validation_time_output` tensor, and you can choose which one you want to execute in your `sess.run`.

#### Warning

You need to make sure that you aren't actually creating new variables to go along with these new ops. To do **that** take a look at the latest documentation on [variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables). It looks like they've simplified it from v0.12, and it essentially boils down to using `tf.get_variable` instead of `tf.Variable` to create your variables.

---

## My preferred work around

Although that is the recommended solution (AFAIK), it is extremely unsatisfying to me; you're creating a whole other set of operations on the graph that just happen to use the same weights. It seems like there's a lot of potential for programmer error by abusing the separation between train time and test/validation time (resulting in the model acting unexpectedly different at these times). Worse; it doesn't solve the problem of `tf.cond` demanding the values for inputs to both branches, it just forces you to copy your whole graph, which is not always possible.

I prefer to just not have my queues in the graph like that, and treat the model as a function which can be fed an example without caring where it's from. That is, I would instantiate the model with a `tf.placeholder` as the input, and at execution time I would use `feed_dict` to actually provide the value. It would function something like this

```py
#inside main training loop
if time_to_train:
    example = sess.run(traingettop)
else:
    example = sess.run(valgettop)
result = sess.run(model_output, {input_placeholder: example})
```

It's very useful to note that you can use the feed_dict to feed any value for any tensor anywhere in your model. So, you can change any model definition that, due to `tf.cond` would always require an input, like:

```py
a = tf.constant(some_value)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
flag = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, [])
one_of_them = tf.cond(flag, a, b)
model_output = build_graph(one_of_them)
```

Into a definition that doesn't, like:

```py
a = tf.constant(some_value)
model_output = build_graph(a)
```

Remembering that you can always overwrite what `a` is at execution time:

```py
# In main training loop,
sess.run(train_op, {a: some_other_value})
```

This essentially pushes the conditional into native python land. In your code you might end up with something like:

```py
if condition_satisfied:
    sess.run(train_op, {a:some_other_value})
else:
    sess.run(train_op)
```

#### Performance concerns

If you are using tensorflow on a single machine, then there is **practically no performance cost** to this solution, as the numpy array/s put into the `example` python variable are actually still stored on the GPU.

If you are using tensorflow in a distributed fashion, then this solution would kill your performance; it would require sending the example from whatever machine it's on to the master so that it can send it back.

Comment: That's a good solution but I don't know how it can be implemented at tensorflow benchmarks here: https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/blob/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks/benchmark_cnn.py

Comment: I had a brief look, and Line #1206 seems to be the line where they actually run the model. Assuming you would otherwise be able to run it then you just need to change that to `results = sess.run(fetches, {tensor_to_overwrite: numpy_array_with_the_values})`. If you need a conditional on whether to do that or do the default, then do that in python before that line.